# Работа с NavigatingCancelEventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Не могу понять как правильно нужно работать с `NavigatingCancelEventArgs` по паттерну MVVM. Через code behind задача решается, но нарушает принцип паттерна.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно поступить.

Comment: Приведите пример кода, так покамест непонятно, для чего вам вообще Navigating. В MVVM-приложениях непонятно, для чего его применять.

Comment: Сейчас не за машиной.
Пример такой, <web browser navigating="blabla"/>
 В самом классе user control

Private void blabla(objeck sender,  Navigating CancelEventArgs e)
{
  И тут мы парсим юрл контрола
Это нужно для того, чтобы забрать ответ от сервера с параметрами
}
И нужно реализовать это в mvvm

Comment: А, у вас компонент WebBrowser? То есть навигация не всей WPF-страницы, а лишь контента в браузере?

Comment: Да, совершенно правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окей, если событие происходит по отношению к компоненте `WebBrowser`, всё не так просто. К сожалению, `WebBrowser` сам по себе «не готов» к data binding'у, он выставляет наружу не команды, а свойства, и даже `Source` не является dependency property.

Поэтому вы, возможно, захотите немного поступиться чистотой подхода MVVM и протянуть ссылку на `WebBrowser` в вашу VM. Там вы сможете управлять им как нужно.

Дело в том, что здесь браузер выступает не только в роли UI, но и обладает собственной, не связанной с отображением бизнес-логикой, а значит, появление его в VM можно считать оправданным.

Пример кода:

View:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Browser}"/>
```

VM:

```
// стандартная имплементация свойства с INPC
WebBrowser browser;
public WebBrowser Browser
{
    get { return browser; }
    set { if (browser != value) { browser = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
}

// создаём браузер, который показывает только гугл, и не может уйти со страницы
Browser = new WebBrowser();
Browser.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
Browser.Navigated += (o, args) => // как только придёт на страницу...
    {
        // ... запретим дальнейшую навигацию
        Browser.Navigating += (o1, args1) => args1.Cancel = true;
    };
```

---

Если вы всё же хотите остаться в рамках «чистого» MVVM, вам придётся обеспечить привязку к свойствам браузера. Для этого обычно «надевают» сверху на объект attached property, к которым уже можно производить data binding. Например, так:

```
class WebBrowserExtension
{
    public static bool GetAllowNavigating(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AllowNavigatingProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAllowNavigating(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AllowNavigatingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowNavigatingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "AllowNavigating", typeof(bool), typeof(WebBrowserExtension),
                new PropertyMetadata(true, OnAllowNavigatingChanged));

    static void OnAllowNavigatingChanged(
        DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var browser = (System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)o;
        var allow = (bool)args.NewValue;
        if (allow)
            browser.Navigating -= DisallowNavigating;
        else
            browser.Navigating += DisallowNavigating;
    }

    static void DisallowNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Теперь вы можете пользоваться браузером так:

```
<WebBrowser Source="http://www.google.com" src:WebBrowserExtension.AllowNavigating="True" />
```

---

На английском SO предлагают attached property для управления и другими свойствами:

- [Is there an MVVM-friendly way to use the WebBrowser control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1384177/276994)
- [load URL into WebBrowser with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14553680/276994)
- [databind the Source property of the WebBrowser in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263551/276994)

Такое протягивание свойств уже довольно сложно, и требует серьёзного обвязочного кода. Поэтому если вы хотите серьёзного управления, путь с `WebBrowser`'ом в VM кажется мне легче.

---

(*Старый ответ, относится к использованию навигации для всего UI, а не для `WebBrowser`'а.*)

При использовании MVVM у вас вовсе не должно быть желания пользоваться этим событием.

При использовании MVVM, изменение UI должно происходить как следствие изменений в VM, а не навигации. То есть, как только поменялся VM-объект, соответствующий странице — автоматически поменялся и UI. Смены UI без смены VM-объекта быть не должно.

Соответственно навигация как метод для подмены UI на уровне UI неприменима.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, стесняюсь спросить. Как протянуть ссылку ?
Что вы имеете ввиду ?

Comment: @ИльяШляховой: Обновил ответ, положил пример кода.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробное разъяснения о контроле.
Теперь хоть имею представление.
Такой вопрос, имеет смысл писать  code behind, если это будет использоваться 1 раз(запрос-ответ  и не будет меняться )?

Comment: @ИльяШляховой: Если это делается один раз — пишите как вам кажется удобнее/легче/правильнее. Если потом возникнут проблемы, всегда можно зарефакторить и поменять. Не стесняйтесь проводить рефакторинг часто и безжалостно, это поможет не заморачиваться на «мелком» дизайне.

Comment: Еще раз, спасибо огромное, удачи вам :)

Comment: @ИльяШляховой: Пожалуйста! И вам!